# Sorting to obtain the largest number

Tags: c++, c++11

Given a list of non-negative integers, I have to arrange them such that they form the largest number when lexically concatenated, and return that resulting number as a string.

Input is: [3, 30, 34, 5, 9]

I tried to traverse the array manually but I didn't understand where I was wrong. All the elements are swapped as I expected but 3 and 30 didn't get swapped. Could anyone please find the error in the code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<int>b={ 3, 30, 34, 5, 9 };



    for(int i=0 ;i<b.size()-1; i++){//i moves from 0 to 3 and picks the ith element
        for(int j=i+1; j<b.size(); j++){
           /*j moves from i+1 to 4 and compares  
            the strings formed by appending int turned strings b[i] and b[j] 
            in two possible orders such as "b[i]b[j]" and "b[j]b[i]"
           */

            std::string str1,str2,str3,str4;

            str1 = to_string(b[i]);
            str2 = to_string(b[j]);
            str3 = str1.append(str2);
            str4 = str2.append(str1);

            if(stoi(str4)>stoi(str3)){
           // if loop swaps if "b[j]b[i]" is greater than "b[i]b[j]"
                swap(b[i],b[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    std::string s="";
    for(int i=0; i<b.size(); i++){//creates string s from sorted array
        s.append(to_string(b[i]));
    }
    std::cout<<s;/*prints largest string that is possible by sorting the elements of array*/

    return 0;
}
```

Expected: `9534330`
Actual: `9534303`

Comment: Why the string comparisons? Why not simply compare the values `A[i]` with `A[j]` directly? And what's the reason for the `append` calls?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but by simply sorting the individual numbers and append them you wont get the biggest result when they can have different number of digits. Counter example: [30 9], sorted solution: 309, correct solution 930.

Comment: Yeah,you are right @ formerlyknownas_463035818

Comment: Thats why append calls are required

Comment: ***How*** should you "form the largest number"? Sum the digits? Use only the "highest" (left-most) digit? Something else? You need to figure that out first before you can start the sorting. And if you want our help you have to tell *us* that.

Comment: We just have to sort the given integers. And then from sorted integers, we have to form a string such that it represents the largest number that can be formed by sorting and appending.

Comment: Example:If array contains 8 and 89 as elements.

Comment: 889 Aand 898 are possible strings.

Comment: But 898 is largest so we have to return that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The question's pretty clear. It even contains an example.

Comment: I think I understand now. In that case I recommend you use [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) on the source vector until you get the "largest number". And if you're not allowed to use standard library functions (assignment restrictions) then I suggest you do some research about *permutations* and how you could do that on a C++ container.

Comment: My approach is like this – 
we compare two numbers XY (Y appended at the end of X) and YX (X appended at the end of Y). If XY is larger, then, in the output, X should come before Y, else Y should come before X. For example, let X and Y be 542 and 60. To compare X and Y, we compare 54260 and 60542. Since 60542 is greater than 54260, we put Y first. –    Please find error in code

Comment: You don't need to convert back to int for comparison, though, you can compare the strings directly. But you implement bubble sort, less efficient almost not possible. Have you considered using `std::sort`? Something like: `std::sort(b.begin(), b.end(), [](int x, int y) { std::string xy = ..., yx = ...; return xy > yx; })`?

Comment: You might have debugged yourself either with debugger (step in the code and/or break point and watch variable values). Or by printing interesting values at runtime [Demo](https://ideone.com/H6kByQ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that you `swap(b[i],b[j]);` but you compare `A`'s values. Quickly, the *A* and *B* arrays become unrelated. Simply use one array. Swap the same array you compare values from.

It will work. Quite surprisingly as the approach feels a bit convoluted, bit it does.

EDIT:

Also,

```
   str1.append(str2);
   str2.append(str1);
```

don't do what you think/expect it to do. The first line modifies `str1`. You'll need to fix that, but I won't do your full homework.

Comment: I tried replacing A[i] with b[i] but still im getting the same error.

Comment: Did you update the code in the question? One of the two vectors should be removed altogether.

Comment: I updated check it once.

Comment: edited the answer. Got it to work. But you'll need to finish it. Good luck, you've got the material you need, now.
And thanks for the interesting approach.